# deferred anti pattern of promises unclear example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

from

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

what promise is he talking about?

```
myApp.factory('Configurations', function (Restangular, MotorRestangular, $q) {
    var getConfigurations = function () {
        //Just return the promise we already have!
        return MotorRestangular.all('Motors').getList().then(function (Motors) {
            //Group by Cofig
            var g = _.groupBy(Motors, 'configuration');
            //Return the mapped array as the value of this promise
            return _.map(g, function (m) {
                return {
                    id: m[0].configuration,
                    configuration: m[0].configuration,
                    sizes: _.map(m, function (a) {
                        return a.sizeMm
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        config: getConfigurations()
    }

});
```

where is a promise? for me it looks more like it's an anti pattern to use his pattern. I cannot see any promise in this code apart from the word `then` nothing makes me think of a promise.

So what does `return MotorRestangular...` actually return?

Comment: it returns a promise of `MotorRestangular.all('Motors').getList().then`. In this case, `.getList()` returns a promise, to which `.then` chains another promise

Comment: so it actually returns the promise and its chained promise. So I can chain more promises to it without harming the order?

Comment: Right, you can chain other promises. Chaining with `.then` is really the async version of sequential code composition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to remember is that, both the `resolve` and `reject` function return a `promise`. In other word, it's already promisified for you. Even if you don't explicitly return something from the `resolve`, what you get is a promise that has been resolved with a value of `undefined`.

In your example, `MotorRestangular.all('Motors').getList()` returns a promise and in the `resolve` function, the first param in `then`, another `resolved` promise is returned which will get the result of `_.map` function as input. It's like:

```
function YourCtrl(Configurations) {
    Configurations.getConfiguration().then(function(resultOfMap) {
        // use resultOfMap here
    })
}
```

*Note:*
Don't get confused by `resolved` and `onFulfilled`. They are kinda the same but the former is for `deferred` object and the latter is from Promise specification.

Comment: he isn't using `resolve` nor `reject` in his example. I just don't understand why `function (Motors) {..}` is a promise.

Comment: @Toskan, `then` signature is `then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`. `onFulfilled` is the resolved which is provided here. Read the [specs](https://promisesaplus.com/) and watch [JavaScript Promises: Thinking Sync in an Async World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc72cyYt8-c)

Comment: it is still very unclear... to make it clear: `getList()` returns an object, the promise object, lets call it `foo`. The code that follows `getList()` e.g. `getList().then(...)` gets stored in that object promise. E.g. just to get the idea, it writes (speculation) something like `foo.then =...` but finally returned, is the object with the information `foo`, which does have the information on what to do `then`. The code in `then` thus is just information on the object `foo` (the promise)

Comment: `then()` returns a new object promise itself. E.g. `var p = deferred.promise; var x = p.then(...); x === p //false, e.g. are not the same, but x knows about p `

Comment: @Toskan, whatever comes out of `then` is already a promise but that's not the same promise that you `then`ed. It's a new promise. If `p` is a promise that returns `a` and you do `p.then(function(a) { return a + "b"; })`, you'll get a new resolved promise with the value of `ab` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
MotorRestangular.all('Motors').getList()
```

is a promise returned by `MotorRestangular`. You can easily chain promises between methods whenever you just make the called function `return` a promise.